# Error while loading shared llibraries for CVC4

Tags: linux, ubuntu, terminal

I keep running into an error in my terminal as I try to test my cvc4 installation.  Here are the steps that I took to do my installation:

***Install Prerequisites***

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install emacs opam libboost-all-dev libreadline-dev
```

***Install CVC4***

```
wget http://cvc4.cs.stanford.edu/downloads/builds/src/cvc4-1.5.tar.gz
tar xfz cvc4-1.5.tar.gz
cd cvc4-1.5
contrib/get-antlr-3.4    

./configure --with-antlr-dir=/home/user/cvc4-1.5/antlr-3.4 ANTLR=/home/user/cvc4-1.5/antlr-3.4/bin/antlr3  --enable-gpl

make

make check

sudo make install
```

***Environment***

I added this line to the end of my ~/.profile:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/local/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH"
```

***Test***

```
cvc4
```

And then I get this error:

```
cvc4: error while loading shared libraries: libcvc4parser.so.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I'm not sure what is wrong.  I'm new to Linux so my apologies if this has an obvious solution.

Comment: Try running the same export command manually in your shell. .profile only runs in a login shell so you may need log out and log in for it to take effect.

Comment: Try either (1) `source  ~/.profile` or (2) log off and then back on. A third, temporary option is running the command with `LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/local/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH" cvc4`.

Comment: Thanks everyone.  I appreciate the help. It seems to be working now.